# edit button is not working in PHP show me page with data that has not being edited

Tags: php, pdo, edit

Good day Stack overflow my edit button is not working when I click the button everything runs as it supposed to but when I return to the page of my table nothing has being edited. So, when code runs it runs as a success query but it not because nothing changed or being edited.

I have tried this code.

```
<?php
$serverHost = "localhost";
$dbname = "products";
$username = "root";
$password = "";

try {
  $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$serverHost; dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
  $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

  if(isset($_POST["update"])) {

    $product_id = trim($_POST["id"]);
    $quanity = trim($_POST["quanity"]);
    $product_price = trim($_POST["productprice"]);


    if(empty($quanity) || empty($product_price)) {
      header("Location:../edit.php?edit=Please fill in the fields");
      exit;

    } else {
      $update = "UPDATE products SET quantity=: quantity, price=: price WHERE id=:id LIMIT 5 "; 
      $data = [
        ': quantity' => $quantity,
        ': price' => $price,
        ':id' => $product_id
      ];
      $statement = $db->prepare($update);
      $statement->execute($data);

      header("Location:products.php?products=product has being successfully updated");
      exit;


    }
   
  


  }

} catch(PDOException  $exception) {
  $errorMessage = $exception->getMessage();
  echo $errorMessage;
}
$db = null;
```

Can you please tell me what is wrong. As I said everything works but the data does not change when I try and update it using the form.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Seems like you have an issue with the named parameters. Both on the prepare() call and the execute() call. Please read the documentation: https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

Answer (score 0):

Hi i hope you have a great day, as you can see
1- Make sure the variable names are correct throughout your code like $quanity, $product_price, $quantity, and $price because i see that you declare $quanity variable but you didnt use it or call it back in your code it seems that $quantity is the correct var and you just miss typed it.
2- In your SQL line , you have spaces in the column names quantity and price that shouldn't be there. Remove the spaces so that the column names are quantity and price (i recommend you to use this line in your SQL Query).
`':quantity' => $quantity, ':price' => $price, ':id' => $product_id`
3 - i just notice that you are using limit 5 in the update query it seems useless and it can affect your code this will limit the number of rows affected by the update to 5. If you intend to update a single row(single product) based on the id, you can remove the LIMIT 5 from the query.

there is the corrected code i recommend i hope it works for you.

```
<?php
$serverHost = "localhost";
$dbname = "products";
$username = "root";
$password = "";


$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$serverHost; dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

if(isset($_POST["update"])) {

    $product_id = trim($_POST["id"]);
    $quantity = trim($_POST["quantity"]);
    $product_price = trim($_POST["productprice"]);

    if(empty($quantity) || empty($product_price)) {
         header("Location:../edit.php?edit=Please fill in the fields");
         exit;
    }
    $update = "UPDATE products SET quantity=:quantity, price=:price WHERE id=:id"; 
    $data = [
      ':quantity' => $quantity,
      ':price' => $product_price,
      ':id' => $product_id
    ];
    $statement = $db->prepare($update);
    $statement->execute($data);

    header("Location:products.php?products=product has been successfully updated");
    exit;
}
```